# What is the difference of using `au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py` and `au Filetype python` in .vimrc?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

As I am setting .vimrc, I found these two code blocks have the same functionality.

```
au Filetype python set
     \ tabstop=4
     \ softtabstop=4
     \ shiftwidth=4
     \ textwidth=79
```

and

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py
    \ set tabstop=4
    \ set softtabstop=4
    \ set shiftwidth=4
    \ set textwidth=79
```

I reckon that there is a very subtle difference between them, but cannot figure it out. Like, vim interprets Filetype when opening the file etc.

Comment: BTWBTW,  au is autocmd

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your intuition is correct: the two autocommands are very similar.

The second autocommand runs when you read or start editing a new file with a name that ends in the `.py` extension. The first runs when the file type is set to Python, which Vim will generally do automatically for `.py` files.

However, try running the following commands with each of the two autocommands in place:

```
:new
:w new.py
```

You will find that the `Filetype` autocommand runs, but the other does not. For this reason, you should probably use the first version if you want to use an autocommand for this.

However, in my opinion, there is an even better solution. Create a file in the location:

```
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim
```

And enter the contents:

```
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set textwidth=79
```

If you don't already have filetype plugins enabled, you will need to do so by adding `plugin` to the `filetype` command in your vimrc file:

```
filetype plugin on
```

This will have the same effect, no autocommands required!

Comment: @SongchengLi I think Vim's Python ftplugin also reads shebangs (so a file with no extension but `#! /usr/bin/python` as the shebang gets detected as a Python file).

Comment: For anyone wondering, here's an explanation for what the `~/.vim/after` directory is for, from the [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way - Plugin Layout](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/42.html#vimafter) chapter: *"Files in this directory will be loaded every time Vim starts, but after the files in `~/.vim/plugin/`."*

Answer (score 0):

The second approach is needed in case Vim don't know the file type.

For tab-separated values I use this on my `vimrc`:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.tsv set ft=tsv
```

And then use FileType as normal. As in the case of using filetype plugin files.

Comment: You could also you an ftdetect script for this, though the line of code would be almost identical.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble. Thanks. I didn't know.