# What is the difference between `au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py` and `au Filetype python` in this specific case?

Tags: vimrc, filetype, plugin-you-complete-me, filetype-python

#### The issue

Consider the following two Vimrc configuration lines for the YouCompleteMe plugin:

```
au BufRead, BufNewFile *.py,*.pyw match BadWhitespace /\s\+$/
```

```
au FileType python match BadWhitespace /\s\+$/
```

When opening an existing file (`vim somefile.py`), the first one loads and works correctly (wrong whitespace gets highlighted), while the second one results in the following error message **but the functionality still works correctly** (wrong whitespace gets highlighted):

```
Error detected while processing BufRead Autocommands for "*.py"..FileType Autocommands for "python":
E28: No such highlight group name: BadWhitespace
```

#### Questions

This issue is confusing on so many aspects...

1. Based on the Q&A linked below, I understood that the two main differences between `BufRead+BufNewFile` vs `FileType` are the following:

- `BufRead+BufNewFile` does not affect writing to an existing file
- `FileType` is not aware of all file formats

However, neither of these explains the reported behavior, because `FileType` is, in fact, aware of Python files, and in this case we are not writing a file (but reading one).

2. Why does the functionality still work in spite of the error message?
3. The error message is slightly confusing, because it talks about `BufRead Autocommands`, whereas the used keyword was `FileType` (and there is no error message when `BufRead` is used for real). So is `FileType` just a wrapper around `BufRead`?

#### Remark

As stated, I am aware of this [Question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18231/what-is-the-difference-of-using-au-bufnewfile-bufread-py-and-au-filetype-py) and the related Answers ([1](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/18232/9602), [2](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/31893/9602)), but as I mentioned, they don't explain the case above. So I believe this is some kind of an edge case and hence a new question is appropriate.

Comment: What creates the BadWhitespace highlight group?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Not sure... For some reason, I thought it was YouCompleteMe plugin, but after some search, I believe that is not the case, so maybe it is not created at all... But then, the question is still open: 1.) Why no error messages in the first case 2.) Why does it still work even if that highlight is not defined.

Comment: Is the space between `BufRead,` and `BufNewFile` really there or is it just a typo in your question?

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: @JürgenKrämer: it is really there (I already saw somewhere else that it is important to have it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BufRead` event is triggered after the `FileType` event if the corresponding `autocommand` is after the `filetype plugin on` command (or after the `plug#end()` call if you are using plug)

I suppose the `BadWhitespace` is defined in between the two.

Which make the the second trigger a warning where the second does not.

Remark: the `FileType` event is not equivalent to the `BufRead` event. But practically it come close for a lot of files. If the file is recognized by Vim there is a `BufRead` `BufNew` event `autocmd` that set the `filetype` (e.g.: in `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim`) triggering the `FileType` event.

Associating your command to `FileType` makes that you associate it indirectly to one of the first `BufRead`. Associating your command to `BufRead` makes that you add it to the list of commands that is already associated to it. It depends where you have it in you `vimrc` But if it is after `filetype plugin on` it is after `FileType`.

Comment: Thanks, I believe this address questions 1 and 2. (`BadWhitespace` is not yet visible when `FileType` is run, but it becomes accessible later.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) What remains open in your question? What is the result of the `:verbose hi BadWhitespace`?

Comment: Thanks Vivian. I believe I understand the difference between `BufRead+BufNew` vs `FileType` better now :)) Result of `:verbose hi BadWhitespace` is the same in **both** cases: `highlight group not found: BadWhitespace`. So apparently it is not defined at all, but the first option swallows the warning (and then, in both cases, I get the highlight anyway for some other reason). I need to look better into it, but I believe you did answer my original question :))

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)